# SQL GROUP BY with a condition?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to copy a table named "CLOUD" to a new one named "t1_temp" while grouping the rows based on a column named "tag". BUT i want this to happen only if the "NeighborhoodID" column is the same.

The query i'm running is:

```
INSERT INTO t1_temp (id, NeighborhoodID, power, tag) 
        SELECT id, NeighborhoodID, SUM(power), tag 
        FROM CLOUD GROUP BY tag ORDER BY NeighborhoodID
```

So for example:
[image]

The third entry shouldn't be grouped with the 1th & 4th entry's because the "NeighborhoodID" isn't the same.

I hope i'm clear, if not please comment, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can group by multiple columns, so:

```
INSERT INTO t1_temp (id, NeighborhoodID, power, tag) 
    SELECT id, NeighborhoodID, SUM(power), tag 
    FROM CLOUD GROUP BY tag, NeighborhoodID ORDER BY NeighborhoodID
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean to add NeighborhoodID also to the group by clause

```
    SELECT id, NeighborhoodID, SUM(power), tag 
    FROM CLOUD
    GROUP BY tag, NeighborhoodID
    ORDER BY NeighborhoodID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO t1_temp (id, NeighborhoodID, power, tag) 
SELECT min(id), NeighborhoodID, SUM(power), tag 
FROM CLOUD 
GROUP BY NeighborhoodID, tag ORDER BY NeighborhoodID
```

Does this help?

Comment: It does @shahkalpesh ! I'd have to mark @Wrikken cause he answered first but appreciate your response pal.